# How to fix Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, where-clause, where-in, mysql-error-1054

this is my error :

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Array to string
>   conversion Filename: templates/sidebar.php Line Number: 24 Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   A:\Sites\PHP_CI\hasan-login\application\views\templates\sidebar.php
>   Line: 24 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: A:\Sites\PHP_CI\hasan-login\application\controllers\Admin.php
>   Line: 14 Function: view
>
> File: A:\Sites\PHP_CI\hasan-login\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT `user_menu`.`id`, `menu` FROM `user_menu` JOIN
>   `user_access_menu` ON `user_menu`.`id` = `user_access_menu`.`menu_id`
>   WHERE `user_access_menu`.`role_id` = Array ORDER BY
>   `user_access_menu`.`menu_id` ASC
>
> Filename: A:/Sites/PHP_CI/hasan-login/system/database/DB_driver.php
>   Line Number: 691

I use php codeigniter. but when I delete the part where the program runs smoothly. maybe an error in the where. how to fix this error?

this is my code :

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
$role_id = $this->session->userdata('role_id');
$queryMenu = "SELECT `user_menu`.`id`, `menu`
                FROM `user_menu` JOIN `user_access_menu`
                 ON `user_menu`.`id` = `user_access_menu`.`menu_id`
            WHERE `user_access_menu`.`role_id` = $role_id
            ORDER BY `user_access_menu`.`menu_id` ASC 
            ";
$menu = $this->db->query($queryMenu)->result_array();
var_dump($menu);
die;
?>
```

Comment: The first line tells you the problem, `$role_id` is an array and you are trying to use it as a string. You need to extract the appropriate value from it (perhaps `$role_id[0]` but without seeing more of your code it's impossible to tell) to use in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is codeigniter, you can use the OOB functions given in [codeigniter query builder page](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html), by the way you should try this one:

```
 <?php
$role_id = $this->session->userdata('role_id');
$queryMenu = "SELECT `user_menu`.`id`, `menu`
                FROM `user_menu` JOIN `user_access_menu`
                 ON `user_menu`.`id` = `user_access_menu`.`menu_id`
            WHERE `user_access_menu`.`role_id` = ?
            ORDER BY `user_access_menu`.`menu_id` ASC 
            ";
$menu = $this->db->query($queryMenu,array($role_id))->result_array();
var_dump($menu);
die;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much
this command worked for me :
$menu = $this->db->query($queryMenu,print_r($role_id))->result_array();

Answer (score 0):

use **printr** on the **$role_id** variable, i suspect its an array and this is why you are getting this error.

Comment: Thank you so much
this command worked for me :
$menu = $this->db->query($queryMenu,print_r($role_id))->result_array();